# Kotlin - vararg -> change query param values

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

in my android app I use Retrofit 2

```
def RETROFIT_VERSION = '2.6.0'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
```

here my service:

```
public enum OperationType {
      PAYMENT,   PAYOUT,  TRANSFER

}



import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.*
import java.util.*

@GET("/operations")
    fun getOperationsList(
        @Query("types") typeList: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards OperationType>,
        @Query("status") statusList: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards OperationStatus>,
        @Query("from") from: Date, @Query("to") to: Date
    ): Call<List<Operation>>
```

here use:

```
val call = restClient.getOperationsList(
            typesList,
            statusList = operationStatusList,
            from = from,
            to = to
        )
```

and here result:

```
 D/OkHttp  (24112): --> GET http://my_ip:8081/operations?types=payment&types=payout&status=executed&from=2019-08-07T00%3A00%3A00&to=2019-08-07T23%3A59%3A59 http/1.1
```

As you can see the param "`type`" pass 2 times. Nice.

Now I use **vararg**  parameter like this:

```
@GET("/operations")
    fun getOperationsList(
        vararg @Query("types") typeList: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards OperationType>,
        @Query("status") statusList: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards OperationStatus>,
        @Query("from") from: Date, @Query("to") to: Date
    ): Call<List<Operation>>
```

and now here result:

```
D/OkHttp  (25017): --> GET http://my_ip:8081/operations?types=%5Bpayment%2C%20payout%5D&status=executed&from=2019-08-07T00%3A00%3A00&to=2019-08-07T23%3A59%3A59 http/1.1
```

as you can see, the param "**type**" now pass in different way. If I decode url I get

```
http://my_ip:8081/operations?types=[payment, payout]&status=executed&from=2019-08-07T00:00:00&to=2019-08-07T23:59:59 http/1.1
```

I need to pass param "**type**" only this way "**type=value&type=value2...**" like this:

```
D/OkHttp  (24112): --> GET http://my_ip:8081/operations?types=payment&types=payout&status=executed&from=2019-08-07T00%3A00%3A00&to=2019-08-07T23%3A59%3A59 http/1.1
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: you have to add again and again the type many times you want, once a query parameter is added, it will add only once

Answer (score 1):

When you use `vararg` you must set the variable's type to the type of a single object, not a whole collection. Change the `typeList` type to `OperationTypes`:

```
@GET("/operations")
fun getOperationsList(
    @Query("types") vararg types: OperationTypes,
    @Query("status") statusList: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards OperationStatus>,
    @Query("from") from: Date, @Query("to") to: Date
): Call<List<Operation>>
```

---

Let me explain how `vararg` works on those examples:

1)

```
fun getOperationsList(vararg types: OperationTypes)
```

In this case the `getOperationsList` method accepts multiple arguments of type `OperationTypes`. Inside its body, the `types` variable would actually be the type of `Array<OperationTypes>`.

You can call the `getOperationsList` like that (I assumed the `OperationTypes` is an enum class):

```
getOperationsList(OperationTypes.PAYMENT, OperationTypes.PAYOUT)

// or using the spread operator
val types = listOf(OperationTypes.PAYMENT, OperationTypes.PAYOUT)
getOperationsList(*types.toTypedArray())
```

and inside the method the `types`' value will be eqivalent to:

```
types = arrayOf(OperationTypes.PAYMENT, OperationTypes.PAYOUT)
```

2)

```
fun getOperationsList(vararg types: List<OperationTypes>)
```

In this scenario, the `getOperationsList` expects its arguments to be multiple *lists* of `OperationTypes` objects. Inside it the `types` variable is the type of `Array<List<OperationsTypes>>`.

The function can be called:

```
getOperationsList(listOf(OperationTypes.PAYMENT, OperationTypes.PAYOUT), listOf(OperationTypes.OTHER_TYPE))
```

and the `types`' value inside will be equivalent to:

```
types = arrayOf(listOf(OperationTypes.PAYMENT, OperationTypes.PAYOUT), listOf(OperationTypes.OTHER_TYPE))
```

That's why your current implementation is not working as you want.

Comment: I can't use single object. Because para, "types" in url many times. Like this: .../operations?type=value1&type=value2...

Comment: @Alexei But that's how the `vararg` syntax works. `vararg types: OperationTypes` means that `types` is an array of `OperationTypes`.

Comment: @Alexei I've edited my answer with some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@GET("/operations")
fun getOperationsList(
    @Query("type") types: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards OperationType>,
    @Query("status") statusList: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards OperationStatus>,
    @Query("from") from: Date, @Query("to") to: Date
): Call<List<Operation>>
```

For another examples: [github](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/parent-1.9.0/retrofit/src/test/java/retrofit/RequestBuilderTest.java#L1092-L1138), [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1226)

Comment: But I need vararg, because sometimes I pass types, but sometimes not.

Comment: Ok, the main difference here is name of the list, `typeList -> types`. You can try same way with vararg.

Comment: I try this:  "@GET("/operations")
    fun getOperationsList(
        vararg @Query("type") types: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards OperationType>,
        @Query("status") statusList: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards OperationStatus>,
        @Query("from") from: Date, @Query("to") to: Date
    ): Call<List<Operation>>" , but it not help - same result

Comment: Note: You said **But I need vararg, because sometimes I pass types, but sometimes not.**. To do this `vararg` is not required at all. You can simply pass null when you dont want to pass types arguments. So you can delete `vararg`.